# how to get subdomain.domain.com in browser and be taken straight to https://subdomain.domain.com/folder/defaultpage in IIS 10.0

Tags: redirect, iis, https, url-rewriting

I am trying to get subdomain.domain.com to load my IIS site without having to enter http:// or https://, but it times out if I don't enter the protocol.   I am using cpanel to redirect subdomain.domain.com to the ip address of my IIS server.  In IIS I have a redirect to https://subdomain.domain.com/folder/defaultpage.  I have URL rewrite installed and am rewriting http requests to https requests.  In IIS Bindings I have removed the port 80 binding, because I want the site to be https only.

I want to enter  subdomain.domain.com in browser and be taken straight to https://subdomain.domain.com/folder/defaultpage

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/folder/defaultpage" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```